# Powerapps patch issues when setting a field by a text label input

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

Im currently having an issue with my Set(scannedUsername,UserBarcodeCI)in Powerapps with the code below
whenever I run the code the patch will update and insert fine into my SQL database table providing the scannedusername is set to a "text" rather than coming from whatever was put in the barcode slot,

This is the code

`Set(clockintime,Now());
Set(ScannedUsername,UserBarcodeCI);
Set(nextPrimaryKey,Max(Filter(Clock_In_out, pkey > 0), pkey) + 1);

Patch(
Clock_In_out,
Defaults(Clock_In_out),
{
pkey:nextPrimaryKey,
username:type(ScannedUsername),
Clock_In_Time:clockintime
//Clock out not set yet
});

Notify("Data Has Been Sent Successfully",NotificationType.Success);
Reset(UserBarcodeCI)`

I have tried;

- changing the Set(ScannedUsername,UserBarcodeCI) to be Set(ScannedUsername,"Text") - This worked
- I have removed the username:(ScannedUsername) - This worked
- I have checked the data Type for the UserBarcodeCI and its set to Format Text
- I have tried wrapping the UserBarcodeCI around a Text() - This didnt work
- I have tried a concatenate around the text - This didnt work
- The field in the database is currently set to a Varchar(50), when changing to Text - This didnt work